# systemd kill process and child with SIGTERM

Tags: systemd, namespace

Hi have a very strange scenario when my process (and its child) receives a `SIGTERM` and the sender is `systemd` (PID == 1). My setup is the following:

- two "simmetric" partitions mounted on `/opt/a` and `/mnt/a`, one primary and one secondary respectively;
- a running `systemd` service unit (executable in `/opt/a/bin/my_exe`) that, on a particular condition, downloads some`.deb` archives and launches a bash script to install them;
- since the files hierarchy in the packages refer to `/opt/a`, the script launches an `unshare` instance, performs a bind mount of `/mnt/a` on `/opt/a` and call `dpkg` to install the package:

```
#!/bin/bash
DEB_PKG="$1"
unshare -m /bin/bash <<-EOF
    mount --bind /mnt/a /opt/a
    dpkg -i --admindir=/opt/a/var/lib/dpkg "\$DEB_PKG"
EOF
```

well, i verified that when the script is called for the .deb package that installs the executable `/opt/a/bin/my_exe`, `systemd` send a `SIGTERM` to both the script and to the running `my_exe`. For all other packages, the installation completes without errors. In addition, if a launch `/opt/a/bin/my_exe` manually all is fine. I suspect that, for some reasons, `systemd` doesn't like some steps in the `postinst` of the package that generates the problem but:

- i cannot figure how it could intercepts them;
- the installation is performed in another partition.

The `postinst` script is the same for all packages:

```
while IFS=' ' read -r f
do
    if [[ -e "$f" && "$f" == /opt/a/* ]]; then
        chown -h obs.obs $f
    fi
done < "$DPKG_ADMINDIR"/info/$DPKG_MAINTSCRIPT_PACKAGE.list
```

EDIT:
This is the systemd `.service` file (very simple):

```
[Unit]
Description=Extensible and configurable updater manager.

[Service]
ExecStart=/opt/a/bin/my_exe -c /opt/a/etc/config.ini
User=obs
Group=obs
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=30

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

EDIT2:
After other investigations, I saw that a running service having its executable replaced by a `.deb` package installation, is killed as well by `SIGTERM`. So it seems that systemd thinks that the replaced executable is that of the running process and not the executable in the other partition. How is this possible? The bind mount is done in a dedicated mount namespace and, inside it, `/opt/a` should refer to `/mnt/a`. I verified that in my shell I don't see the bind mount:

```
$ findmnt | grep "/opt/a"
|-/opt/a                            /dev/sda6          ext4     rw,relatime,sync,data=ordered
```

While I see the bind mount inside the mount namespace created by `unshare`:

```
# nsenter -m -t $(pidof update_script.sh) /bin/bash
# findmnt | grep "/opt/a"
|-/opt/a                            /dev/sda6          ext4     rw,relatime,sync,data=ordered
| `-/opt/a                          /dev/sda5          ext4     rw,relatime,sync,data=ordered
```

Comment: Need to see your systemd service file for this.  Likely it is just timing out and you need to adjust the timeouts.

Comment: Hi, i've edited my question with `.service` file. What timeouts are you speaking about?

Comment: Probably because you are not using `Type=oneshot`? (Not sure if even that has a default timeout though.)

Comment: If the timeouts are not in the file, you can see them with `systemctl show my.service | grep -i timeout`  which I should have suggested too.

Comment: `TimeoutStartSec` is the parameter most likely involved, except that if type=oneshot timeout is disabled by default,